# How to detect using microsoft .bat files is file empty?

Tags: batch-file

and exectute some command if file empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a sample batch file that does this. You call it with the name of the file you want to check is empty or not:

```
@ECHO OFF

IF "%~z1"=="0" GOTO FileEmpty
ECHO File is not empty
GOTO End

:FileEmpty
ECHO File is empty

:End
```

Note that the file must exist in order for this to work. But you can check that easily with `IF EXIST`